# IP.Board clicking on "Edit User Profile" redirects to login page

Tags: ipb

I have a small problem on a site. Like in the title, when any user, on any skin variation, wants to use the button `Edit Profile` in his profile. It redirects him to the login page. But when you use the button `Edit Header Image`, it brings you to the customization panel, where all the other options of `Edit Profile` are. But that's just a walk-around. I'm looking for a solution to resolve this issue.

Under `Edit Profile` I have the following link:

```
name_of_site.pl/index.php?&app=core&module=global&section=login&do=form
```

And under the `Edit Header Image` I have this:

```
index.php?app=core&module=usercp&tab=core&area=customize
```

I was trying to find that code with the `Find and Replace` function in themes, but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, or has a link to any resource I can read and find the solution?

Thank you for reading and for any help in advance! :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Bump, just refreshing :) The problem still persists.

Comment: Any info about the platform you are using will be really helpful. You didn't get any answer because of that. If you meant Wordpress theme, then write it there. It's really hard to understand your question.